# Script Out and Export MS Access Macros to SQL

Tags: sql-server, excel, vba, ms-access, macros

I have dozens of macros of the form:

[image]

What I wish to do is script out the entire macro in SQL. I know this can be accomplished manually, by opening a query and selecting `SQL View`. 
For example, the first query `Build BOM - Part 0A`, if opened and selecting `SQL view` would display:

`DELETE FROM [BOM Cost];`

Is there a way to accomplish this automatically for the entire macro without needing to go into each and every Query and Macro?

Comment: Do it once with the macro recorder and you will have the base code for what you want.

Comment: @AlbertD.Kallal to clarify, I am suggesting to be able to get the SQL script of the macro/query, not to use SQL to script out...(also please be more constructive in your comments)

Comment: @AlbertD.Kallal I never thought I'd have to write this, but please stop using "rodeo clown" on the site. There's never a time where it's appropriate to compare somebody else to a rodeo clown, whether they be drunk or unemployed.

Comment: @meagar for the record I am neither, just trying to get this db into a format that I understand, ie. SQL server

Answer (score 2):

You can use VBA code to get (at least some of) what you need. For example, you can iterate through all of the Macros in the current database with

```vbs
Dim m As Object
For Each m In CurrentProject.AllMacros
    Dim macroName As String
    macroName = m.Name
    Debug.Print macroName
Next
```

Now instead of simply printing the macro name, you could dump it into a text file with

```vbs
Application.SaveAsText acMacro, macroName, "C:\Users\Gord\Desktop\macroDump.txt"
```

which will produce a file that looks like this

```
Version =196611
PublishOption =1
ColumnsShown =0
Begin
    Action ="OpenQuery"
    Argument ="MyUpdateQuery"
    Argument ="0"
    Argument ="1"
End
Begin
    Comment ="_AXL:<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-16\" standalone=\"no\"?>\015\012<UserI"
        "nterfaceMacro MinimumClientDesignVersion=\"14.0.0000.0000\" xmlns=\"http://schem"
        "as.microsoft.com/office/accessservices/2009/11/application\" xmlns:a=\"http://sc"
        "hemas.microsoft.com/office/acc"
End
Begin
    Comment ="_AXL:essservices/2009/11/forms\"><Statements><Action Name=\"OpenQuery\"><Argumen"
        "t Name=\"QueryName\">MyUpdateQuery</Argument></Action></Statements></UserInterfa"
        "ceMacro>"
End
```

You could then parse that file, looking for Begin/End blocks that contain `Action ="OpenQuery"` and retrieving the query name. With that you could open the QueryDef object and retrieve its SQL

```vbs
Dim cdb As DAO.Database
Set cdb = CurrentDb
Dim qdf As DAO.QueryDef
Set qdf = cdb.QueryDefs(queryName)  ' MyUpdateQuery
Dim querySql As String
querySql = qdf.SQL
```

Answer (score 0):

While not fully automated and similar to @GordThompson's suggestion, consider gathering all query names manually in each macro into a VBA array and then iterate through the [QueryDefs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff194892.aspx) collection, writing each to a growing file:

```vb
Public Sub ExtractSQL()
    Dim db As DAO.Database, qdef As DAO.Querydef
    Dim qrys As Variant, qry As Variant
    Dim strSQL As String, sqlFile As String

    Set db = CurrentDb        
    qrys = Array("Query1", "Query2", "Query3")

    sqlFile = "C:\Path\To\AllQueries.sql"

    ' OPEN SQL TEXT FILE
    Open sqlFile For Output As #1

    For Each qdef In db.QueryDefs        
        For Each qry In qrys

            If qdef.Name = qry Then                                    
                    Print #1, qdef.SQL      ' SQL STATEMENT
                    Print #1, ""            ' LINE SEPARATOR                    
            End If

        Next qry
    Next qdef

    ' CLOSE SQL TEXT FILE
    Close #1
    Set qdef = Nothing
    Set db = Nothing

End Sub
```

Do note: Access SQL is not readily compliant in SQL Server's T-SQL. The two dialects differ a bit. So, some translation is required including `IIF()` to `CASE` (if using SQL Server before 2012); no use of double quotes to enclose string literals; no crosstab pivots; and other items.